# event propogation when opening bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal button inside a div. I want it so that when I click on the button the modal opens but it ignores any programming for the outside div. I can get this to work using  event.stopPropagation(); but the modal won't open. Can anybody see how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="testdiv" style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:Beige;padding:40px;"> 
 <button id="openmodal" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#testdiv").click(function(){
    alert("Only show when the outside area is clicked")
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#openmodal").click(function(){
event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Open the modal and only show this alert")
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the modal on button click and remove the modal reference from the `button` that is remove `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"`.Use `.modal('show')` to open the modal on button click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testdiv").click(function() {
    alert("Only show when the outside area is clicked")
  });

  $("#openmodal").click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    alert("Open the modal and only show this alert")
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<div id="testdiv" style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:Beige;padding:40px;">
  <button id="openmodal" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```